# how to fix Object of class Illuminate\Support\Collection could not be converted to int?

Tags: php, laravel, web

I want to retrieve the data that stores the total questions on a quiz, but when I loop using the result of the total question data that I got using the query below, the result shows Object of class Illuminate \ Support \ Collection could not be converted to int. does anyone know how to solve it?

[Here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKxYM.jpg)

Here is my code

```
 public function insertStdAnswer(Request $request,$id){
        $_num = DB::table('quiz')
                    ->select('question_total')
                    ->where('id', $id)
                    ->get();

        for($i = 0; $i <= $_num ; $i++){
            $quiz_id = $id;
            $user_id_std_quiz = Auth::id();
            $std_answer = $request->input('answer-'.$i);
            $nomor_quiz = $request->input('soal-'.$i);
            DB::insert('insert into studentquiz (`std_quiz_id`,`user_id_std_quiz`,`std_answer`,`nomor_quiz`) values(?,?,?,?)',
            [$quiz_id,$user_id_std_quiz,$std_answer, $nomor_quiz]);
        }
```

Comment: are you expecting the `quiz` table to have more than one record with the same 'id'?

Comment: `DB::table('quiz')->select('question_total')->where('id', $id)->get();` returns a collection. If you need the ids you just queried then you should loop through the collection. `foreach($_num as $quiz)` If you need the number or rows then `$_num->count()`

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use ->value('question_total')

```
$_num = DB::table('quiz')
                ->where('id', $id)
                ->value('question_total');
```

Answer (score 0):

use count($_num) instead of $_num in for loop
You are comparing $i with a collection.

Answer (score -1):

As you are using `$_num` to assign data which you have queried form the database using the get() method, your `$_num` has become a collection object, as any query in `Laravel` returns a collection object. To use it in your `for()` loop as in `integer` value you will have to `count` the collection to get an integer value. you can use the following code instead of your current for loop:

```
for($i = 0; $i <= count($_num) ; $i++){
    // your code
 }
```